# Two XML files but accessing second XML control in first activity

Tags: android

First_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
           android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent"  
           android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

          <TextView android:id="@+id/tactiveDateDisplay"  
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" /> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

Second_layout.xml

```
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
           android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent"  
           android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

          <TextView android:id="@+id/tactiveDateDisplay1"  
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" /> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
   {
     TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    call();
}
      private void call() 
{
    setContentView(R.layout.seccond);//second xml file
    //At this line i want to access  the second layout textview control
}

   }
```

This is My code so How to access the second_layout.xml file control TextView  in MainActvity.java file

Comment: K i am adding the code also

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
   {
     TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
  Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity_1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
 public class MainActivity_1 extends Activity
   {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.seccond);//second xml file
    //At this line i want to access  the second layout textview control
}
In Androidmanifest.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

the first and second layout is for one Activity?

if yes, you can create one layout with visibility visible or gone.

i think that you should create one activity for each layout, and call activity with startActivity.